%dofuture% foreach file not found warning
Trying to get %dofuture% to work, but getting an error using the following code. Not sure why.
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(doFuture)

plan(multisession,workers=availableCores())

# Create a .bat file in your downloads folder called "Example1.bat" including the following:
# @ECHO OFF
# ECHO Such a useful reproducible code...

Folder.Path <- "C:/Users/Insert.Name.Here/Downloads/"
setwd(Folder.Path)
system2("Example1.bat") # this runs as expected
foreach(i=1)%do%{system2(paste0("Example",i,".bat"))} # this runs as expected
foreach(i=1)%dopar%{system2(paste0("Example",i,".bat"))} # this runs as expected
foreach(i=1)%dofuture%{system2(paste0("Example",i,".bat"))} # this returns a warning

This is the warning message I get when I use %dofuture%
Warning message:
In system2(paste0("Example", i, ".bat")) : '"Example1.bat"' not found

Your displayed error implies that you have a typo past0 instead of paste0. Regardless, we expect that you submit a [mcve], i.e. code that we can all run ourselves to reproduce your stated issue.

I've provided reproducible code for your convenience

Thanks to Henrik Bengtsson: The order of operations matters here
First: setwd()
Second: plan(multisession,workers=availableCores())
If you do the opposite order (as I did above), meaning plan() first and setwd() second, the workers don't follow into the new working directory.

I do not recommend relying on the order of those two commands - that is unstable code. Instead, I recommend specifying the full path and not relying on what the working directory is, which I write in https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/discussions/730#discussioncomment-9951236.
